# C++11 vector of smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, smart-pointers

Suppose we have the following codes. We have following classes

- Animal as AbstractClass
- Dog and Bird which is subclass of Animal
- Zoo which keeps all animals

_

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    void HasWings() = 0;
};

class Bird : public Animal
{
public:
    Bird() : Animal() {}
    void HasWings() override { return true; }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog() : Animal() {}
    void HasWings() override { return false; }
};

class Zoo
{
public:
    Zoo() {}
    void AddAnimal(Animal* animal) { _animals.push_back(animal); }
    ...
    std::vector<Animal*> _animals;
};

void myTest()
{
    Zoo myZoo;
    Bird* bird = new Bird();
    Dog* dog = new Dog();

    myZoo.AddAnimal(bird);
    myZoo.AddAnimal(dog);

    for (auto animal : myZoo._animals)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I hope to replace vector of pointers by vector of smart pointers. i.e,

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> _animals;
```

How do we change the code for Zoo and myTest?
I find difficulty on updating the code, especially the method "AddAnimal" in Zoo class

```
auto bird = std::make_shared<Bird>();
auto dog = std::make_shared<Dog>();
myZoo.AddAnimal(bird);
myZoo.AddAnimal(dog);
```

bird and dog are different type

Comment: `AddAnimal(std::shared_ptr<Animal> animal)` - `shared_ptr<Bird>` and `shared_ptr<Dog>` will convert to `shared_ptr<Animal>` since the former two are derived from the latter. Also `Animal::HasWings` is missing `virtual` and since you already have a virtual member function you should probably also make `Animal`'s destructor `virtual`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behaviour of `std::shared_ptr` is very similar to that of a raw pointer with respect to the `*` and `->` operators (in fact, the dereferencing operators are "forwarded" to the internal raw pointer stored by the `std::shared_ptr`). In particular, you can use a `std::shared_ptr` to a base class for virtual dispatching along a class hierarchy. For example, the code below does exactly what one assumes, namely calls the appropriate function at runtime:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Base
{
    virtual void f() { std::cout << "Base::f()" << std::endl;}
    virtual ~Base() = default; // to silence -Wall warnings
};

struct Derived: Base
{
    void f() override { std::cout << "Derived::f()" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vsp; // access Derived via shared_ptr to Base

    auto base = std::make_shared<Base>();
    auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();

    vsp.push_back(base);
    vsp.push_back(derived);

    for(auto&& elem: vsp)
        elem->f(); // virtual dispatch
}
```

So, most of the time, it is enough to replace `Animal*` with `std::shared_ptr<Animal>`, and the code will just work. Things are a bit more complicated with `std::unique_ptr`, as the latter is a move-only type (you cannot copy it), so one must be more careful.

Comment: You are right. If I use std::unique_ptr instead of std::shared_ptr because I cannot create a method to return pointer of Animal like old days. 
i.e., "Animal* GetAnimal(int index);"

Comment: Say Base and Derived are little complex classes, having some functions and members, how will you, how will you destruct the vector vsp before main ends and avoid memory leak?

Comment: @Annie first do `vsp.resize(0)`, then you can also do `base.reset(); derived.reset();` to release the initial shared pointers (remember that the reference count is increased by 1 when pushing into the vector).